# Anzograph Docker container exits immediately with error code 12

Tags: docker, anzograph

I followed the instructions in the [Anzograph documentation](https://docs.cambridgesemantics.com/anzograph/v2.4/userdoc/deploy-docker.htm#mac) to deploy Anzograph with Docker. My operating system is MacOS (M1).

The exact command I used to create the container was:

```
docker run -d -p 80:8080 -p 443:8443 \
-v ~/Documents/Code/graph_query_sampler-main/anzograph:/opt/anzograph-shared \
--name=anzograph-gqs --platform linux/amd64 cambridgesemantics/anzograph:latest
```

Every time I run the container, it stays active for about 5-10 seconds and then exits with error code 12 and the log shows the following:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0020-anzograph-ctrl-plane-activation.sh

INFO /docker-entrypoint.sh: AnzoGraph control plane is not started

INFO /docker-entrypoint.sh: Starting AnzoGraph control plane\n

INFO /docker-entrypoint.sh: AnzoGraph control plane startup triggered

INFO /docker-entrypoint.sh: Wait for AnzoGraph control plane to come up

INFO /docker-entrypoint.sh: port 5600 at localhost is up


/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0030-anzograph-db-activation.sh

INFO /docker-entrypoint.sh: AnzoGraph database is not started

INFO /docker-entrypoint.sh: Starting AnzoGraph databaseStarting AnzoGraph...

Error on Node 0 (IP:127.0.0.1) - 9: Database did not start


INFO /docker-entrypoint.sh: Logs from /tmp/azgmgrd.log:

2022-05-23 23:35:01.448975Z: [167:167] Reading /opt/anzograph/config/ip_addrs.conf

2022-05-23 23:35:01.455549Z: [167:167] AzgState: NotStarted 

2022-05-23 23:35:01.455968Z: [167:167] =============== AnzoGraph 2.5.4.r202205091419 #beefe557541884c213b9eebf159af8cd6bed97c7 ===============

2022-05-23 23:35:01.456004Z: [167:167] System manager startup

2022-05-23 23:35:01.462240Z: [171:173] Starting DB monitoring ....

2022-05-23 23:35:01.467035Z: [171:173] g_scan_db_pids_file: false

2022-05-23 23:35:01.483852Z: [171:171] Preparing for secure connections

2022-05-23 23:35:01.526362Z: [171:171] Sysmgrd 0 listening on 0.0.0.0:5600

2022-05-23 23:35:01.907411Z: [171:177] StartGqe request on node 0

2022-05-23 23:35:01.907528Z: [171:177] waitfor_sibling_mgrs

2022-05-23 23:35:01.907741Z: [171:177] GetStatus request on node 0

2022-05-23 23:35:01.940742Z: [171:177] AzgState: Starting 

2022-05-23 23:35:01.941459Z: [171:177] Crash DIR name: 706664101

2022-05-23 23:35:01.944115Z: [171:177] Last sysmrd start time: 0

2022-05-23 23:35:01.944169Z: [171:177] Time /opt/anzograph/config/settings.conf modified: 706664097

2022-05-23 23:35:01.944514Z: [171:177] Sending settings.conf to /opt/anzograph/config on 0 compute nodes

2022-05-23 23:35:01.946966Z: [171:205] Launched /opt/anzograph/bin/azgd -node 0 -time 706664101 -errpipe /tmp/sbxbooterr.np0 -internal /opt/anzograph/internal -pidfile /tmp/azgpids.log  

2022-05-23 23:35:12.447876Z: [171:177] 

  -----------------------------------------------

  error:     Database did not start

             

  code:      1030

  entity:    9

  location:  quiet_dbstart() in gsysmgrd.cpp:1024

  time:      706664112391238 2022-05-23T23:35:12.391238Z

  pid:       171

  thread:    205

  -----------------------------------------------

ERROR /docker-entrypoint.sh[12]: Failed to start AnzoGraph database
```

When I run `docker inspect anzograph-gqs` I get this output:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "9898475cc03688d26b5bffbc417d96208d50b6882094627e9c0d44e8c2f0b8f1",
        "Created": "2022-05-23T22:54:37.125375459Z",
        "Path": "tini",
        "Args": [
            "--",
            "/docker-entrypoint.sh",
            "/opt/anzograph/bin/azgmgrd"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 12,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2022-05-23T22:55:44.687921546Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2022-05-23T22:55:58.397889719Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:bc6ffaa7c240ccf787f3192e6d6009fa631e37a387af7c00eca791c9a775f127",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/9898475cc03688d26b5bffbc417d96208d50b6882094627e9c0d44e8c2f0b8f1/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/9898475cc03688d26b5bffbc417d96208d50b6882094627e9c0d44e8c2f0b8f1/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/9898475cc03688d26b5bffbc417d96208d50b6882094627e9c0d44e8c2f0b8f1/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/9898475cc03688d26b5bffbc417d96208d50b6882094627e9c0d44e8c2f0b8f1/9898475cc03688d26b5bffbc417d96208d50b6882094627e9c0d44e8c2f0b8f1-json.log",
        "Name": "/anzograph-gqs",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/Users/fredrik/Documents/Code/graph_query_sampler-main/anzograph:/opt/anzograph-shared"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ],
                "8443/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "443"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "private",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": null,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4634d1711725edecbd4cf4f8aa1614774dc7540caa347a3b71f742eb8615d716-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d3d70efb9e9d91e6502eeccf48118d5ef567e78bf7612c0d09813d0a6e8ecd83/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dcd24d87ed2ffa178360bb16605bd9726c2fbd29e3d497ad2a9892c38dff4081/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c671ce63b8c831094b9b801a35011a79b99a083ce51702e4b4dee7d5e8274d49/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b896058c82c6d6d711e90c059841912e019ad341314b56e3d04dc4c13055e3c8/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/93fdc914268cc3eafc2908101264de0117a6e8abe6d985eaa309a182aefaa2d7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7850b3b2a45a83e3268736861601f49c0906a79b83009f59f0af457e80925591/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c585c392aaa501c6678692edd80d37193c818c3964d0d9ffbaa7cbacd1b1acf4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e443fc3dcc5180caadd853d69778776081a1a9a37fb251b1d9da68220d9ae4ab/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f58b67a7dde229373f14d05501442f40a8205d7bc5561ea91e8b8f6367248573/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ffe837015a0415391b139bcb3067cd5831ccaa94c94d3529072fe8e8bcb95ca0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/75e1d823155de18a4067bf1e6a4558f0db3c45aa57e34fb6c19fa98903eeea76/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/78e54b21f985fa4bc0b592ab58823eb07153d34a02c9acbe97c70b3be74de5ad/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6e401c30de70bec0361c73907773aedb7b5a50d23a0e925121b28bc37278d958/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c092986416d81f14701619ecba9102fcc0c1d063fac494536a519d6cb9c545aa/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d497b435bef048d094590f776e0614088645afc004d3a654bce8b32795f1db20/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e702c9af4817b9978a4f4459aade77c6e5cad2883670787206c57a52fe4c0f52/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/160e9fcfe99fa566e054dcf3980cf03b73502f0462b82a5fd957116e1f6f447e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d1ea21d7e6410c8719579040bd5f9bfb1b1cf4c49a06a7b054de2c9fcdb9e28c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3400ec74b5e54fa73604cc3c0086b942afe81d4ad2d4b30d2a6185beb7c24061/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a0d05dc3a6b0d50be96e6c492f59bcad4985f62f6585448581b44579fa58c448/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a4bb97d0649db5a948ffcec269cd6519344e4468ca3e24125675b6fac56d2263/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/19398d2762122f4e6c811c20ed5afbaba3605f484fb0c7a252f07dcce2ea24f4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/454966381d364fc9c3d6bf10f30041ed5feb3167838bb8ba7734d1c409642d88/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4634d1711725edecbd4cf4f8aa1614774dc7540caa347a3b71f742eb8615d716/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4634d1711725edecbd4cf4f8aa1614774dc7540caa347a3b71f742eb8615d716/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4634d1711725edecbd4cf4f8aa1614774dc7540caa347a3b71f742eb8615d716/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/Users/fredrik/Documents/Code/graph_query_sampler-main/anzograph",
                "Destination": "/opt/anzograph-shared",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "d5cf1a27062200b4aa8d1eee39faf5cb4a8ae9f3eda56320cdf12fb5b811dd76",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/d5cf1a27062200b4aa8d1eee39faf5cb4a8ae9f3eda56320cdf12fb5b811dd76/_data",
                "Destination": "/opt/anzograph/persistence",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "9898475cc036",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5600/tcp": {},
                "5700/tcp": {},
                "8080/tcp": {},
                "8100/tcp": {},
                "8101/tcp": {},
                "8102/tcp": {},
                "8103/tcp": {},
                "8104/tcp": {},
                "8105/tcp": {},
                "8106/tcp": {},
                "8107/tcp": {},
                "8108/tcp": {},
                "8109/tcp": {},
                "8110/tcp": {},
                "8111/tcp": {},
                "8112/tcp": {},
                "8113/tcp": {},
                "8114/tcp": {},
                "8115/tcp": {},
                "8116/tcp": {},
                "8117/tcp": {},
                "8118/tcp": {},
                "8119/tcp": {},
                "8120/tcp": {},
                "8121/tcp": {},
                "8122/tcp": {},
                "8123/tcp": {},
                "8124/tcp": {},
                "8125/tcp": {},
                "8126/tcp": {},
                "8127/tcp": {},
                "8128/tcp": {},
                "8129/tcp": {},
                "8130/tcp": {},
                "8131/tcp": {},
                "8132/tcp": {},
                "8133/tcp": {},
                "8134/tcp": {},
                "8135/tcp": {},
                "8136/tcp": {},
                "8137/tcp": {},
                "8138/tcp": {},
                "8139/tcp": {},
                "8140/tcp": {},
                "8141/tcp": {},
                "8142/tcp": {},
                "8143/tcp": {},
                "8144/tcp": {},
                "8145/tcp": {},
                "8146/tcp": {},
                "8147/tcp": {},
                "8148/tcp": {},
                "8149/tcp": {},
                "8150/tcp": {},
                "8151/tcp": {},
                "8152/tcp": {},
                "8153/tcp": {},
                "8154/tcp": {},
                "8155/tcp": {},
                "8156/tcp": {},
                "8157/tcp": {},
                "8158/tcp": {},
                "8159/tcp": {},
                "8160/tcp": {},
                "8161/tcp": {},
                "8162/tcp": {},
                "8163/tcp": {},
                "8164/tcp": {},
                "8165/tcp": {},
                "8166/tcp": {},
                "8167/tcp": {},
                "8168/tcp": {},
                "8169/tcp": {},
                "8170/tcp": {},
                "8171/tcp": {},
                "8172/tcp": {},
                "8173/tcp": {},
                "8174/tcp": {},
                "8175/tcp": {},
                "8176/tcp": {},
                "8177/tcp": {},
                "8178/tcp": {},
                "8179/tcp": {},
                "8180/tcp": {},
                "8181/tcp": {},
                "8182/tcp": {},
                "8183/tcp": {},
                "8184/tcp": {},
                "8185/tcp": {},
                "8186/tcp": {},
                "8187/tcp": {},
                "8188/tcp": {},
                "8189/tcp": {},
                "8190/tcp": {},
                "8191/tcp": {},
                "8192/tcp": {},
                "8193/tcp": {},
                "8194/tcp": {},
                "8195/tcp": {},
                "8196/tcp": {},
                "8197/tcp": {},
                "8198/tcp": {},
                "8199/tcp": {},
                "8200/tcp": {},
                "8443/tcp": {},
                "9100/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/anzograph/bin:/opt/anzograph/tools/bin:/opt/jetty/bin",
                "JETTY_HOME=/opt/jetty",
                "JETTY_BASE=/opt/jetty/frontend",
                "JETTY_USER=jetty",
                "JETTY_LOG=logs",
                "container=docker",
                "UDX_LOGS=/opt/anzograph/internal/log",
                "AZG_HOME=/opt/anzograph"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/opt/anzograph/bin/azgmgrd"
            ],
            "Healthcheck": {
                "Test": [
                    "NONE"
                ]
            },
            "Image": "cambridgesemantics/anzograph:latest",
            "Volumes": {
                "/opt/anzograph/persistence": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/opt/anzograph",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "tini",
                "--",
                "/docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "architecture": "x86_64",
                "build": "r202205091419",
                "build-date": "20220511191744",
                "build_date": "20220504160009",
                "com.cambridgesemantics.anzograph.frontend.build": "i202205101246",
                "com.cambridgesemantics.anzograph.release": "2.5.4",
                "com.cambridgesemantics.anzograph.udx.cpp.release": "202205111737(udx/cpp/centos7/release/2.5.4)",
                "com.cambridgesemantics.anzograph.udx.java.release": "202205111737(udx/java/release/2.5.4)",
                "com.cambridgesemantics.vendor": "CentOS, Cambridge Semantics Inc.",
                "com.github.openjdk": "11.0.14.1.1-1.el7_9",
                "description": "AnzoGraph® DB is the only MPP (massively parallel processing) native graph OLAP (GOLAP) database designed to accelerate data integration and scalable analytics with graph at performance levels that compare favorably with the industry-leading data warehouse analytics products. AnzoGraph offers a variety of advanced analytics capabilities, including over 40 functions for regular data warehousing-style line-of-business analytics like Aggregate grouping, Views, Windowed Aggregates, as well as graph algorithms, and Iinferencing at super-fast speeds. An SDK enables developers to add their own custom parallel bi-directional connectors, functions and aggregates that can perform in parallel across enterprise-scale knowledge-graphs. The product has been market tested and has been in production for several years at leading global corporations.",
                "maintainer": "support@cambridgesemantics.com",
                "name": "AnzoGraph® allinone image",
                "org.centos": "centos7.9.2009",
                "org.eclipse.jetty": "9.4.45.v20220203",
                "org.label-schema.license": "GPLv2",
                "org.label-schema.name": "11.0.14.1.1-1.el7_9 jre11 Image",
                "org.label-schema.schema-version": "1.0",
                "org.label-schema.vendor": "CentOS, Cambridge Semantics Inc.",
                "release": "2.5.4",
                "summary": "AnzoGraph®, allinone image based on centos7",
                "url": "https://cambridgesemantics.com/",
                "vendor": "Cambridge Semantics Inc.",
                "version": "r202205091419"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "71e096a6ed5fccff773db70434cb9161691bea0f680381b7366f2bdc2862c67a",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/71e096a6ed5f",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "3904c44c76c8a4a268dd9355dcec5559f06320c7011cf3b2cccf72786acb3b59",
                    "EndpointID": "",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I'm quite certain I followed the documentation correctly, and yet it doesn't work. I would very much appreciate some help if anyone knows a solution.

Comment: The host path on a volume mapping (`-v` option on `docker run`) must be absolute to be bind mounts. See info on `host-src` here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems

Comment: @HansKilian that **is** an absolute path. The `~` will be replaced by the full path to the home directory of the current user.